# Make MineSweeper Game using Qt5 & c++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, minesweeper

I tried to create the Minesweeper game using Qt5 and Qtcreator and I have source code without GUI,I tried to write it using the GUI,but did not get the right result.

Now I have an array of button ( I got this from this forum).
This code creates an array of buttons, when the user clicks on one of the buttons, displays the coordinates of this button and I want to send the coordinates to a function.

The function returns several image urls and coordinates .
I want change the icons of the buttons that have these coordinates and images urls.

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a{argc, argv};
   QWidget window;
   QGridLayout layout{&window};
   QVarLengthArray<QPushButton, 100> buttons(100);
   QLabel display;

   const int rows = 10, columns = 10;
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++ i)
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
         auto text = QStringLiteral("(%1,%2)").arg(i).arg(j);
         auto & button = buttons[i*columns+j];
         //button.setText(text);
         button.setIcon(QIcon("url"));

         layout.addWidget(&button, i, j);
         auto & but = buttons[i*columns+j];
         QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&display, text] {
             display.setText(text);
         });
        }
    layout.addWidget(&display, rows, 0, 1, columns);
    window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

If you have another solution, please share it by me .

Comment: what is your question? You say you dont get the right result, but from your description it is not clear what is the "right result" or what is the problem with the code you have

Comment: Sorry, I did not use the correct word, I meant that I could not write it .

Comment: Write your coordinate-using code inside of the lambda in the connect call, of course remembering to capture `i` and `j` – the lambda has a capture list and you should understand its meaning first.